# How to apply the amount of a raise given user's last name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a section of my code that inputs the user's information into the system in order to determine if they get a raise. Ideally I would use variables and search the information given, however for my class I have to have a `class` statement.

```
class User:

   num_of_users=0
   raise_amount = 1.04

   def __init__(self, first, last, spend):
       self.first=first
       self.last=last
       self.spend=spend
       self.email=first + "." + last + "@company.com"

       User.num_of_users += 1

   def fullname(self):
       return "{} {}".format(self.first, self.last)

   def apply_raise(self):
       self.spend= self.spend*self.raise_amount

first=input("Enter in your first name:")
last=input("Enter your last name:")
spend=int(input("Enter in your availbe spend amount. This must be a positive number:"))

# these are hypothetical users in my system

user1=User(first,last,spend)
user2=User("Ryan", "Weber", 1000)
user3=User("Grant", "Freeland", 3000)
user4=User("Vicki", "Lepper", 1000)
user5=User("Haley", "Lepper", 500)

if last=={"Lepper"}:
    user1.apply_raise=1.2

else:
    user1.applyraise=1.04

print(user1.applyraise)
```

Comment: you seem to be confusing methods and instance variables. `apply_raise` is a method your of class that should be called with an argument like so `user1.apply_raise(1.2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the code below is based on what you have (modified to follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

I **think** it does what you say you want to do.
One issue may be that that it will apply the raise to *every* user with the same last name, so you might want to also check the first name.

```
class User:
    num_of_users = 0
    raise_amount = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, spend):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.spend = spend
        self.email = '{}.{}@company.com'.format(self.first, self.last)
        User.num_of_users += 1

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self, raise_amount=None):
        if raise_amount is None:
            raise_amount = User.raise_amount  # use default
        self.spend = self.spend * self.raise_amount

# Hypothetical users in my system.
users = [
    User('Ryan', 'Weber', 1000),
    User('Grant', 'Freeland', 3000),
    User('Vicki', 'Lepper', 1000),
    User('Haley', 'Lepper', 500)
]

first = input('Enter in your first name:')
last = input('Enter your last name:')
spend = int(input('Enter in your available spend amount. This must be a positive number:'))

for user in users:
    if user.last == last:
        user.apply_raise(1.2)
        print(user.spend)
```